# Windows Service Onstart issues with two services

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

I have 2 service in servicebase which has a onstart method is infinate loop (done using AsyncReadContext way) but when start a service it is starting the service which is first in the list and never and coming to onstart of second service.
Some code:

```
           ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                            new Service1(),
                new Service 2(),
            };

            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Onstart:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
//read MsMQ async way
}
```

Service 1 is reading the queue but service 2 is not reading the queue. Its the same code when i change service 2 to first in the list then service 2 is reading the queue. Here queues for the two service are different.

Answer (score 2):

You should kick off another thread in the OnStart - method which does the actual work.

For example with an anonymous method:

```
var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
   //Actual work here
}));
t.Start();
```

This causes the OnStart method to finish right away and should also startup your second service.

Answer (score 0):

There were issues in my code. Two services Service1 and service 2 and not installed by serviceinstaller. when I changed to serviceIntaller and ServiceInstaller to ProjectInstaller. I was 1093 Error and service cant be started and this because service names of the services are same once I changed to class name of the service issue is resolved.